# Provision user(s) at grafana start-up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana

I want to spin-up a grafana container with a pre-configured user, with only view permission. While one can easily configure the admin user with the `GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER` and `GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD` environment variables or in the [`grafana.ini`-file](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/), I cannot find an option to add an initial standard user.

One can easily mount the `grafana.ini`-file to the container, e.g. in docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana-oss:10.2.0
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - ./grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini:ro
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=AdminUser
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=PASSW0RD
```

but there is just no option to create users to the local SQLlite database.

**Idea: config-container + REST api**

The only way, I can think of is to spin up a second container that adds a user via REST, e.g. in an alpine container with a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

curl -X POST \
  "http://AdminUser:PASSW0RD@grafana:3000/api/admin/users" \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "name": "TestUser",
    "login": "TestUser",
    "password": "TestUserPassword"
}'
```

This is more or less the same idea as configuring grafana after start-up with ansible [as suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888870/how-can-i-import-users-and-teams-to-grafana).

**Idea: users.yaml**  *| not working*

Asking ChatGPT, it constantly suggests to mount a YAML file (e.g. call it `grafana_users.yaml`) with the users to `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/users.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: 1

users:
  - name: TestUser
    password: TestUserPassword
    role: Editor
```

and adding the following bind to the docker-compose config:

```
    volumes:
      - ./grafana_users.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/users.yaml:ro
```

According to the logs, this has no effect and the suggestion of ChatGPT refers to grafana 7.x anyway ...

---

Any idea of how to create users automatically at provisioning with less permissions than the admin? (without spinning up a second container just for provisioning -- which would also only needed to be started at first start-up and not at every `docker compose up`.)

Comment: ChatGPT hallucinates! Check Grafana doc and you will find that user provisioning doesn't in Grafana.